# Как сделать равноудаленные inline блоки?

Tags: html, css

БЕЗ ФЛЕКСБОКСА И ГРИДОВ, нужна бОльшая поддержка браузеров

3 inline блока шириной по 32% (если задавать чтобы было почти ровно 33%, один из блоков уже переходит на другую строку). Как сделать чтобы блоки были равноудалены друг от друга в пределах контейнера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько бОльшая поддержка браузеров нужна-то?

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов для ie8+

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%">контент</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%text-align:center">контент</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%text-align:right;">контент</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение.
Отредактировал вопрос, а если уже более 3х блоков?

Comment: Тогда можно применить text-align:justify. вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/77/ . Обратите внимание на :before он должен быть inline-block и width:100%, без него не заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через функцию `calc()`. CSS-переменные использованы чисто для иллюстрации, можно вставлять число, равное количеству колонок вручную.

```css
:root {
  --columns-count: 4; /* это число должно совпадать с количеством колонок */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / var(--columns-count));
}

div + div {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD. Свойство поддерживается ИЕ, но [не поддерживается Сафари](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last).

---

Воспользуйтесь [свойством `text-align-last`](https://webref.ru/css/text-align-last). Оно похоже на `text-align`, но действует на последнюю строку текста. С его помощью можно растянуть по ширине текст, в котором одна единственная строка.

```
text-align-last: justify;
```

> Строка выравнивается по ширине. Если в последней строке только одно слово, то оно будет выравнено по левому краю.

```css
.justify-inline-blocks {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
.item {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="justify-inline-blocks">
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<div class="justify-inline-blocks">
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<div class="justify-inline-blocks">
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<div class="justify-inline-blocks">
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<div class="justify-inline-blocks">
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Три блока(`display: inline-block`) в ряд с шириной 33.3%.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.container__item {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container__item-red {
  background: red;
}
.container__item-blue {
  background: lightblue;
}
.container__item-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item container__item-red"></div>
  <div class="container__item container__item-blue"></div>
  <div class="container__item container__item-green"></div>
</div>
```